# Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Click'

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com

I'm running the below code with PowerShell and it runs successfully on one server but not the other. Both servers are running Windows Server R2 Standard with IE 8. The script runs in Admin mode, also in IE, "Enable Protected Mode" is turned off for Local Intranet.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true 
$ie.Navigate("http://localhost/testwebsite")
While ($ie.Busy) {Sleep 3}
$doc = $ie.Document
$btn = $doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
$Button = $btn | ? {$_.Name -eq "refreshBtn"}
$Button.Click()
$ie.Quit()
```

And here is the error I get on one of the boxes (note: don't receive this error on the other machine):

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Click'.
```

Is there a security setting I need to change on the server? Do I need to adjust my script? Anything else?

BTW: I've checked various posts on StackOverflow regarding issues related to this and so far I haven't found anything that's helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that there's more than one button with 'refreshBtn' name; that's why `$button` in an array (of button type) and not a single button that has the `click()` method to call.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right. There are two buttons with 'refreshBtn'

Comment: I made the following change to my code and it now works: `$Button[1].Click()`. Thanks for the tip C.B!!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why its different, but it looks like your pipeline

```
$Button = $btn | ? {$_.Name -eq "refreshBtn"}
```

is returning multiple buttons, so `$Button` is actually an array.  PowerShell 3 handles this better: it will actually call `Click()` on every element in the array. Upgrading to PowerShell 3 is probably not an option.

You can workaround this a couple ways.  First, add the `Click()` method call to the pipeline which finds the button:

```
$doc.getElementsByTagName("input") | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "refreshBtn" } | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Click() }
```

Of course, you may consider it an error if you're getting back multiple buttons.  In that case, you'll want to handle it:

```
$Button = $doc.getElementsByTagName("input") | 
              Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "refreshBtn"}
if( $Button -is 'Object[]' )
{
    Write-Error ('Found multiple <refreshBtn> buttons.')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Splattered Bits. There are actually two buttons on the page and I need to click both, so your solution above works well.

Comment: Your `Foreach-Object... click()` works, however why doesn't `getElementsByTagName(...)[0].Click()` work? I'm selecting the first item in the array.